# How to get multiple responses at once

Tags: postman

I'm doing a POST Request and after adding a value in the body inside

> x-www-form-urlencoded

I was able to get the response that i want in the body the html that i want ... however the problem now is there is thousands of values that i want to add doing that manually can take forever each time i have to add one value and then copy the response ... i tried to add all the values by editing bulk edit but it didn't work postman only execute one value

Comment: @Anime, make yourself clear please. Nothing is understandable from what you've written. Start from the beginning. What happens after you get response and what you want to do?

Comment: i added Post request link then i add the key and value in the body not the headers ! i get the response that i want now i have thousands and thousands of key and value that i want to test i can't do it manually

Comment: @Amime, so automate it once and don't check it manually. Tab "Tests" in postman will fit your wishes.